# VB.NET Pinvoke: How to fix the structure address passed into DLL?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a DLL written in C (compiled using VC++2017). There are several functions accept pointers to a structure.

During the init call, it will save the address passed in. And during later calls, the DLL expects that the passed in addresses is the same as the first init call.

In vb.net, I define a structure (packed as 4), I checked the memory layout, it's exactly the same as C when passed into the DLL.

However, each time I called a function using the structure (ByRef), the address may or may not change (shift for 4 bytes).

Am I missing anything Or is it even possible to do that in VB.NET?

The codes are as follows, the c struct (It's legacy code and I'd prefer not to change this),

```
struct A
{
    char a[9] ;
    char b[9] ;
    char c[2] ;
    char d[9] ;
    int e;
    int f;
    char g[2] ;
    char h[9] ;
    int i;
    int j;
    char k[2] ;
    int l;
    char m[41] ;
    char n[41] ;
    char o[10] ;
} ;
```

This is what I defined in VB.NET,

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=4)>
Structure A
    <VBFixedArray(9), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=9)> Dim a() As Byte
    <VBFixedArray(9), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=9)> Dim b() As Byte
    <VBFixedArray(2), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> Dim c() As Byte
    <VBFixedArray(9), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=9)> Dim d() As Byte
    Dim e As Integer
    Dim f As Integer
    <VBFixedArray(2), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> Dim g() As Byte
    <VBFixedArray(9), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=9)> Dim h() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    <VBFixedArray(2), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=2)> Dim k() As Byte
    Dim l As Integer
    <VBFixedArray(41), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=41)> Dim m() As Byte
    <VBFixedArray(41), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=41)> Dim n() As Byte
    <VBFixedArray(10), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=10)> Public o() As Byte
End Structure
```

These are the C prototype:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) int __stdcall init(struct A * param1)
__declspec( dllexport ) int __stdcall dosomething(struct A * param1)
```

These are the VB.NET prototype

```
Public Declare Function init Lib "A.dll" (ByRef param1 As A) As Integer
Public Declare Function dosomething Lib "A.dll" (ByRef param1 As A) As Integer

Dim a As New A
'ok
init(a)
' ok
dosomething(a)
' The second call to dosomething, the param1's address changed by 4 bytes
dosomething(a)
```

The above is just the simplified version. You get the idea that the param1's address in C changes during the different calls.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Storing that pointer is a very questionable practice in C as well.  Easier to get away with perhaps, but then it just won't much sense anymore to have to pass that pointer to dosomething() as well.  Since you already have the pointer.  A handle-based design would be more sensible, the init() function then *returns* the pointer.  Anyhoo, you must change the parameter to ByVal param As IntPtr and marshal the struct in your vb.net code.  Ouch if dosomething() makes changes, you have to marshal back.  You in effect do what the C code should have done, more painfully since it is just memcpy() in C.

Comment: @HansPassant The original C code was legacy, and used by VB6. We are upgrading it to VB.Net (and recompile the C code using VC++2017 too). It'd better not to modify the C part unless absolutely necessary, because understanding all the memory mess behind it takes time and is out of our budget. I understand that the legacy C (written more than 20 years ago) shouldn't really expect that the memory address passed in are always the same, if there's no way in .Net, then modifying C will probably be our only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly natural that the address of the marshaled struct is different in each call. That's because the marshaler has to create an unmanaged struct to send to the unmanaged code. The managed structure does not have the same layout as the unmanaged struct which makes this necessary. And even if the managed and unmanaged structs had compatible layout (i.e. the struct was blittable), the address might change because the .net memory manager can move objects.

You can however, take charge of the marshaling process. Allocate some unmanaged memory (e.g. by calling `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, and then use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to populate that memory with a marshaled version of the structure. You can then pass the address of that unmanaged memory to the unmanged code. When you have finished all your calls to the unmanaged code, call `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to read any modifications made to the structure.

Perhaps the bigger question is why feel the need for the address to be stable between calls. I'm finding it very hard to imagine a scenario where that is a reasonable expectation to put on the caller. Is it possible that your unmanaged code is taking liberties by requiring this of the caller?